# How to use spacy lemmatiser with a different pos taging

Tags: spacy

I am working on POS tagging tasks through different libraries (including pattern) as well as lemmatization tasks.

Everytime I use the spacy lemmatisation, it automaticaly generates a spacy pos tag for every word in the sentence.

However, I would like to use the pos tag generated by pattern (not from spacy) to improve the lemmatisation of the sentence.

Is that something possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently looking into this problem as well. Here are some things I found out, hope it will point you in the right direction.

- lemmatizer is created by BaseDefaults.create_lemmatizer(see https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/spacy/language.py). You can access it by calling nlp.Defaults.create_lemmatizer
- lemmatizer lives at nlp.vocab.morphology.lemmatizer (see https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/morphology.pyx)
- lemmatizer is called when tokenizer's exceptions are added during tokenizer's instantiation (if lemma is not supplied as a part of the exception definition).
- lemmatizer is called from Tagger.set_annotations => vocab.morphology.assign_tag_id (see https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/spacy/pipeline.pyx for Tagger class, and https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/morphology.pyx)

Tagger is a part of the spaCy pipeline.

Looks like what you need to do is:

- disable spacy POS tagger, and create and plug in your own (there's info here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines)
- create your own lemmatizer pipe element, which will call nlp.vocab.morphology.lemmatizer with the tags your tagger assigned. Or maybe a better solution would be to create your own instance of the lemmatizer by calling nlp.Defaults.create_lemmatizer and then use that one.

Hope this helps.